# Filtering Django QuerySet by ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I want to grab a recordset by its foreign key using the filter term. But somehow this is not working. I'm showing the models here:

```
class MessageMonitoring(models.Model):
    MyID                   =  models.ForeignKey(AboutMe, null=True, blank=True, related_name='MessageMonitor')

class AboutMe(models.Model):
    MyGender                   = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = GENDER_CHOICES)
```

In my view I'd like to do the following:

```
recipient = AboutMe.objects.get(pk=toid)
monitor_recip =  MessageMonitoring.objects.filter(MessageMonitor_owner=recipient)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'MessageMonitor_owner' into field. Choices are: MyID, ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting `MessageMonitor_owner` - that's neither a model name nor a field on the model you showed. To filter using the models and foreign key relation that you're showing, use:

```
monitor_recip = MessageMonitoring.objects.filter(MyID=recipient)
```

Or, if you don't need the recipient object for anything else in the view, save some DB use by filtering against its PK rather than retrieving the object:

```
monitor_recip = MessageMonitoring.objects.filter(MyID_id=toid)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had forgotten this!